# Finding the right HTTP parameters to make request with PHP

Tags: php, http, post, get, request

I would know how could I find rights parameters to use to make php `POST` or `GET` request on various websites, catch results and parse them in a php code.

I'll explain more...
I want to use some search engines of the various websites to make product research, so I want to find what parameter I could use to make `POST/GET` requests. I don't want to have to find these parameters manually because they can be different from one website to another.

the manual possibility is to make first research and copy it manually in a php code like this when the resulting URL is caught:

`$keyword='mykeyword';
$url = 'https://www.monsite/query='.$keyword;`

but I don't want to do that
I try to find a method to inject plain text directly into the research  of a search engine and catch the following URL. so finally I just need to open this URL and parse the results.

anyone could help me? Is it possible to inject data directly into HTML  or are they dependent on HTML code and could be varied from a webpage to another?

my previous question was closed because it seems to be off-topic, please leave me a message this time if this one seems too. and I'll correct it if I can?

Comment: I think Magnus Eriksson's comment is the main point on your previous question.  At the moment it looks as though you are at the very early stages and looking more for a method on how to do it rather than having a specific problem implementing your method.  Perhaps if you narrow it down to 1 site and practice with that one first, then see if/how that method works with other sites.

Comment: i fact i think i just would to know if text injection in input field can be done easily with only one 'POST' or 'GET' request.